# Pass value of form field in the url (params/$get)

Tags: forms, ajax

I have created a form (with entityform) and wants to pass the value of the first field in the parameters of the url. This value is useful for update the other fields of the form.
Is there a method to achieve this ? I have read several posts with the ajax callback subject, but exactly I don't see how to process...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve? Is this first field going to change what other fields in the form will show/do?